# Transclude ignoring template text

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can anyone tell me why in the example below the text "Say Hello" is not being included in the transclusion? So you can see the button and the "Goodbye" link but not the text from the template.

Many thanks

```
<greeting ng-transclude>
    <a href="">Goodbye</a>
  </greeting>

  <script>
  angular.module('myApp', []).directive('greeting', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude : true,
      template: "<button class='btn'>Say Hello</button>"
    };
  });
  </script>
```

[Fiddle here:)](http://jsfiddle.net/screenm0nkey/58yAU/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template: "<button class='btn'>Say Hello</button>"
```

Should be:

```
template: "<button class='btn' ng-transclude>Say Hello</button>"
```

It's mean's use inner of ng-transclude prop's code instead of the original.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. "Multiple directives [ngTransclude, ngTransclude] asking for 'ngTransclude' controller" Adding 'ng-transclude to the template and removing it from the markup seems to achieve the same thing as the way it works now.

Comment: The directive `ng-transclude` is a marker directive, which indicates where the transcluded content should be nested. Use `<greeting>Goodbye</greeting>` in the **html markup** and use something like `template: '<button class="btn" ng-transclude></button>'` in your **directive definition**.

Comment: Following along with @null point, it sounds like you may want:  `template: "<button class='btn'><span ng-transclude></span>Say Hello Greeting 1</button>"` (and remove the `ng-transclude` from `<greeting ng-transclude>`)- this will add the transcluded text rather than replacing the existing button text

Comment: +1 Hey KayakDave, i probably mislead everyone with the question a little but in that I know how to fix it using a span and I understand how transclusion works. I just wondered whether there was a way to do it without adding span tags. Thanks for your answer.